# Internet Explorer deletes cookies used by Web browser control C#

Tags: c#, cookies, webbrowser-control

i have an application which sets a cookie upon authentication, there is a web browser control within this application to navigate a web application which uses this cookie for authentication.

The problem is, if we have the option 'Delete browsing history on exit' along with cookies checked, then when the last instance of IE is closed, the cookie that is being used by my Web browser control is also deleted, inspite of my web browser control being open.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the cookie store is commonly used by IE and the embedded WebBrowser control. If by any means you delete the IE cookies, the ActiveX's cookies will be deleted as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i would understand if the cookie is deleted manually, however Internet Explorer deleting that cookie while a session is active, shouldn't be happening.